# Automatically find short regexp to match a set of words?

Tags: regex, machine-learning

I am not looking for a specific regular expression, but for a *software* that find them.

Let us say I have a file A and a file B: how to find a regexp that matches all words of A, but does not match any of the words in A?

If A contains "truit fruit" and B contains "ridiculous", then the software could return something like ".*ru.*" but '.*r.*' only would be invalid.

It is the "practical" aspect of another question [1], though what interests me is to find an actual software that solves it in practice.

Thanks for your help,

Nathann

[1] https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/is-finding-the-minimum-regular-expression-an-np-complete-problem

Answer (score 1):

There is no algorithm to somehow "cleverly derive" a regular expression from examples. You can only implement a brute force attempt of an iteration through all permutations of common substrings of the words in A and tests B against it until you find a solution. You are not guaranteed to find a solution, though.

For the case that there are no common substrings of all words in A you could then extend that approach to introduce the "or" operator in regular expressions. But that get's really ugly and slow.

If that does not lead to a solution, then you'd have to go on extending your attempts such that also exclusion rules are added to the expression by iterating through all words in B and creating anti patterns from it. Horrible attempt.

And as said: you are never guaranteed to find a solution.

---

There is one thing though:

If you are not interested in *how* the final regular expression looks like you can do this: create a regex simply combining all words in a "whitespace padded version of A" with an "or" operation (so `\struit\s|\sfruit\s` in your example). Obviously that attempt creates huge expressions. You then would have to take care to exclude exact substrings that might occur in B again. Which may lead to much longer expressions still.

---

Bottom line: there is no really elegant solution for this. Simply because the question does not allow for that. Question is: why does it have to be a regular expression? Why can't you simply do string comparisions? That would probably not be more expensive anyway in such an vaguely defined scenario...